# How to create table/view with data from another SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a database managed by a third party vendor and have access to read-only for the tables and views. I would like to be able to create a table from this database in a remote server. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Hey this is what I got from SELECT @@VERSION
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-GDR) (KB4057115) - 11.0.6260.1 (X64)   Jan  9 2018 21:31:12   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: What kind server do you use? ms sql?

Comment: i think so.. i run the basic queries on ms sql server management studio 18

Comment: Welcome to the world of SQL :) I've edited your question to add the SQL Server tag. One thing to know is that various flavours of SQL have different capabilities so it's important to add this info. To get even more specific can you run `SELECT @@VERSION` then edit the question and add the tag for the version

Comment: Your remote SQL Server will need network access. The simplest approach in the first instance is to follow this guide to create a a linked server (in the server that will contain the new table) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15. There are many ways to do what you want to do and this is just one of them.

Comment: Do you need live data that is current whenever accessed? Is it sufficient to pull a copy of that table (perhaps peridiocally) into your database using whatever ETL tools you have?

Comment: @smor the data gets refreshed at EOD pulling from various sources, calculating and storing for that date which gets accumulated over time. so technically, im pulling static copy of data everyday... if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the linked server, if the server of third party vendor is SQL Server, follow the following steps. If the server of third party vendor is not SQL Server, you need to choose other data source, and sometimes need to install the OLE DB driver.

First, enter the connection path of the third party vendor.

[image]

Second, enter the account and password.

[image]

[image]

Third, create the view.

[image]

The query format will be

```sql
SELECT Column1, Column2 ...
FROM [server path].[db name].[dbo].[table name]
```

Reference: [How to create and configure a linked server in SQL Server Management Studio](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/)

Comment: thank you so much for the help, i'll try this out today (been dragged into a few other projects since the post)

Comment: @MichaelYoo Does it solve your question?

Comment: Hi Epic Chen, I get an error saying denied permission to create a Linked Server when following the steps above.. :( sorry for the delayed response, been a nightmare trying to get up to speed at a new firm I just joined.